# amazon s3 and django - Allow only the users from my website and not the anonymous users

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am using amazon s3 to store uploaded user images. My problems are:

- If I permit or grantee for me, I cannot upload or download the contents.
- If I permit or grantee for everyone, all the users and (especially) anonymous users will be able to see the contents, which I don't want.

So, my question is, what do I do so that only the users from my website can upload, download and delete the content?

In that I have conditions that:

1. Only the users (user1, user2, user3, ...) who are following the user
   (user0) can download/view the content?
2. Only the user who uploaded the view can delete the content.

models.py:

```
def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" %(str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)

PRIVACY = (
    ('H','Hide'),
    ('F','Followers'),
    ('A','All'),
)

class Status(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    privacy = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=PRIVACY, default='F')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

settings.py:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'FAKEAMAZONKEY'

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'FAKEAMAZONSECRETKEY'

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'fakebucketname'
```

**Update**

Model for relationship between users

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship', 
                                           symmetrical=False, 
                                           related_name='related_to')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def add_relationship(self, person, status):
        relationship, created = Relationship.objects.get_or_create(
            from_person=self,
            to_person=person,
            status=status)
        return relationship

    def remove_relationship(self, person, status):
        Relationship.objects.filter(
            from_person=self, 
            to_person=person,
            status=status).delete()
        return

    def get_relationships(self, status):
        return self.relationships.filter(
            to_people__status=status, 
            to_people__from_person=self)

    def get_related_to(self, status):
        return self.related_to.filter(
            from_people__status=status, 
            from_people__to_person=self)

    def get_following(self):
        return self.get_relationships(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)

    def get_followers(self):
        return self.get_related_to(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)

    def get_friends(self):
        return self.relationships.filter(
            to_people__status=RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING, 
            to_people__from_person=self,
            from_people__status=RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING, 
            from_people__to_person=self)


RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING = 1
RELATIONSHIP_BLOCKED = 2
RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES = (
    (RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING, 'Following'),
    (RELATIONSHIP_BLOCKED, 'Blocked'),
)

class Relationship(models.Model):
    from_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='from_people')
    to_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='to_people')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.from_person, self.get_status_display(), self.to_person)


class Activity(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name="content_type")
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    element_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name="element_type", blank=True, null=True)
    element_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    element_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('element_type', 'element_id')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Activity'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Activities'
        ordering = ['-pub_date']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ("%s %s") % (self.actor.username, self.action)

    def get_rendered_html(self, user=None):
        if self.element_type:
            template_name = '%s_activity.html' %(self.element_type.name)
        else:
            template_name = '%s_activity.html' %(self.content_type.name)

        return render_to_string(template_name, {
            'object':self.content_object,
            'actor':self.actor,
            'action':self.action,
            'element_object':self.element_object,
            'user':user,
            'pub_date':self.pub_date
            })
```

Comment: You need to change your s3 permissions to only allow downloads from your server, and the backend webapp needs to filter out who can make requests to the s3 file.  I'm using symfony so cannot help much.  If you do not add restrictions to s3, then anyone with the link can download the file from s3 and that is a data breech. [Look at bucket policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

Comment: @George Yes, that's what I want. I have added your comment as useful. I hope someone will help me out.

Comment: look at the [doc and video from aws](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/roles-usingrole-ec2instance.html)

Comment: I sure hope those aren't your real keys

Comment: They aren't... the first thing i did was check if those keys work. You can imagine there are bots scraping every site for keys like these... and amazon keys are especially easy to scrape.

Comment: @BraveNewCurrency yep they aren't real keys!

Comment: @vlad-ardelean You are right... That's the reason.

Answer (score 7):

When loading the files directly you can use [Amazon's Query String Authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth) where you have to include a signature into the URL to verify that you are allowed to get the files.
Your app can use boto's [`Key.generate_url` method](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.generate_url) to create such an url. You should also add an expiry time after which the link will not be valid anymore.

EDIT: A more detailled [description](http://tartarus.org/james/diary/2013/07/18/fun-with-django-storage-backends) about how to set this up using boto,,,

Answer (score 3):

Since boto3 is out, we can use:
https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/docs/source/guide/s3-presigned-urls.rst

```py
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
try:
    response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod=client_method_name,
                                                Params=method_parameters,
                                                ExpiresIn=expiration,
                                                HttpMethod=http_method)
except ClientError as e:
    logging.error(e)
    return None
# The response contains the presigned URL
return response
```

We can also use similar method for uploading objects in the same ref link.

Comment: The users can then share this presigned url and bypass the security if I understand it correctly

Answer (score 2):

So as George said, you need to take 2 steps to make this work, although instead of granting access to ec2 instances (never used that method) i recommend just granting rights to your specific keys (have used this method extensively)

1. Allow full control to the bucket resources to the user you wish.

Here are the amazon on how permissions work. They are not trivial, so you need to understand who the principal account is, and whether you're using its keys or the keys for an IAM user. Regardless, your keys should have full access to the resources (Hope it's your bucket, not someone else's, cuz then things a little more complicated)
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html

2. Implement business logic to:

   - allow your app users to create S3 files
   - allow users who are following user X to view/ download files created by user X
   - allow only user X to delete files that he created

For creating the resources:
  - if the backend you provided works, and you've configured your S3 rights well, you shouldn't have to do anything. However, to check that your keys are not an issue, do this:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection as s3c
connection = s3c('your-aws-access-key', 'your-aws-secret-key')
bucket = connection.get_bucket('your-bucket-name')

new_key = bucket.new_key('your-key-name')  #meaning the name of the file
# https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/s3/bucket.py#L611

new_key.send_file(file_object)  #this will upload the file
# https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/s3/key.py#L709
```

If everything works well, you should be able to see your file in the S3 browser - if not, you'll have to get back to the documentation about S3 access rights.

To only allow users who are following user X have access to the files that user uploaded:
Your `models.py` file doesn't say how you've implemented the `follow` logic. I can't tell who is following who. Do you have your own custom `User` model? Do you use Django's but with an extension? Do you have your own model which links users? Share more information about how one user 'follows' another, and then I could even share code fragments.

To allow user X to delete its own files:
I'm guessing that the Status.user field will already contain a reference to the user that created the image. If so: put this in your view:

```
def picture_deletion_view(request, status_identifier ...):
    try:
        status = Status.objects.filter(id_or_some_identifier=status_identifier)
    except Status.DoesNotExist:
        return SomeHttpResponse()

    if request.user.id == status.user.id:
        # you can delete the picture and redirect... to somewhere
    else:
        # you can't delete! redirect...or something
```

Comment: I have added the logic of relationship. Please have a look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is logic which is handled by the view and template. 
In the template for example you can have a block like this `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` with a uploadform and in the view you can check also if the user in authenticated and only then load your stuff to s3

Comment: Yes, but I have entirely different problem. Suppose one has the link to your image (which is very easy to get), he/she can easily view the image even if he/she is not the user.

Comment: You can create a user in the amazon IAM section and than set `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME`, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` to upload to your bucket. I think you can also set the amazon CORS settings to allow only request from your domain

Answer (score -1):

so i can't speak to the aws.s3 piece, but for django, the best way to limit who has access to a view is to require login through django's `login_required` decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

or, if you want to expose all of the view, but not parts of the page (links, etc), you could put that information into the template, as @t_io said, but the django docs strongly recommend against putting too much processing logic in the templates, as it slows down the site. it would be better to put that information in the view:

```
@login_required
def image_view(request):
    user = request.user

    # this list has the user's own images
    mine = []
    for status in user.status_set.all():
        mine.append(status.image)

    # this list has the images the user can see (relationship-based)
    following = []
    friends = []

    # you can get the person from the user
    person = user.person

    for status in person.get_friends().all():
        friends.append(status.image)

    for status in person.get_following().all():
        following.append(status.image)

    ctx = dict(user=request.user, friends=friends, following=following, mine=mine)
    return render("template.html", ctx)
```

and in the template, you could walk the lists

```
{% for img in mine %}
    <li><a href=...></a></li>
{% endfor %}

{% for img in following %}
    <li><a href=...></a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

...you get the idea

to prevent people from just navigating directly to the media url, you could use sendfile (python library), or the apache/nginx equivalent. so you'd need another view:

```
import sendfile
from django.conf import settings
@login_required
def handle_media(request, path=None):
    try:
        requested_file = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
        return sendfile.sendfile(request, requested_file)
    except:
        pass

    return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Page not found {}</h1>'.format(path))
```

and then you'd need an additional url (urls.py):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'/media/(?P<path>[a-zA-Z0-9_- /]+)$', views.handle_media),
)
```

see [django-sendfile](https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile) for use on sendfile

Comment: yes tha't one way. But the thing is if you get the link of an image, you can easily get that just by going to that url...